# How to refetch all queries after a mutation?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Using apollo graphql, I have a mutation that modify the "Person" object in the database

All throughout the app, I have various queries to fetch that from "Person". Sometimes I need the whole object, sometimes only the name or the age. There is a list of persons (generated using the PERSON_IDS query) and when an item in the list is clicked, a dialog open with all the person's data (fetched using PERSON_DATA)

queries:

```
export const PERSON_IDS = graphql(`
  query personNames($familyId: String!) {
    family(query: { id: $familyId }) {
      persons {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`)

export const PERSON_DATA = graphql(`
  query person($personId: String!) {
    person(query: { id: $personId }) {
      id
      name
      age
      height
      weight
    }
  }
`)

export const PERSON_NAMES = graphql(`
  query personNames($familyId: String!) {
    family(query: { id: $familyId }) {
      persons {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

(The actual app is more complex, there are many different mutations)

mutation

```
export const UPDATE_PERSON = graphql(`
  mutation updatePerson($personId: String!, $person: PersonUpdateInput!) {
    updateOnePerson(query: { id: $personId }, set: $person) {
      id
    }
  }
`)
```

I call the mutation using

```
const [updatePerson] = useMutation(UPDATE_PERSON, {
  refetchQueries: [PERSON_IDS]
})
```

After the person is updated, the person_ids list is refreshed, but the other queries return the old data!

I can't add all the queries in the refetchQueries array because there are a lot. Furthermore, I get a warning if I add a query that has never been used before

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the modified data from the mutation and no other query will need to refetch.

So if your mutation updates `name` and `height`:

```js
export const UPDATE_PERSON = graphql(`
  mutation updatePerson($personId: String!, $person: PersonUpdateInput!) {
    updateOnePerson(query: { id: $personId }, set: $person) {
      id
      name
      height
    }
  }
`)
```

that will automatically update the `name` and `height` you get back in all queries returning `Person` with that `id`. No need to make even one additional query.